# Rancher/Docker containers on OSX cannot ping by hostname

Tags: rancher

Thought I would test out Rancher and running into a small issue.

I have a rancher-server (1.6.10) setup on DigitalOcean. I have a rancher-agent setup on my laptop (a mac using docker for mac).

Containers create just fine from the Rancher Server UI and run on my laptop.

I needed to expose some ports on a few containers that I could access from my laptop (like db interface), due to some issues with docker for mac and cattle managed networking, I switched all the containers to be in bridged mode and assigned a hostname to them.

However, from within the container, I cannot ping any other containers by the given hostname.

Is this a problem with Docker for OSX, or Rancher, or both? Is there a workaround?

I can ping other containers by IP address, just not by hostname.

I'm creating everything in the UI right now for testing. There is no yaml.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Docker for Mac is not supported, because the games it plays to pretend ports are mapped to the Mac's IP and there is not really a Linux VM running in the background are not compatible with CNI drivers/managing port mapping with iptables.  So the IPSec ports aren't reachable and it is not possible to construct a working cross-host network.

Comment: I posted this before on slack. I'll leave it up, though. Thanks!